# How to declare empty or not-empty dtd element

Tags: xml, dtd

How can I declare an element in DTD that is self-closing or contains elements? I have found the `*`-operator, but I can't verify if this can also validate empty elements.

I have tried this, but it gives a compilation error in Visual Studio saying that the `EMPTY` element is not declared:

```
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations|EMPTY)>
<!ELEMENT Annotations (State*)>
<!ELEMENT State EMPTY>
```

Or I could try the following, but I can't validate if it is ok:

```
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations?)>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your element declaration for `File` is correct:

```
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations?)>
```

What you're saying is that `File` can contain zero or one `Annotations` element.

Also, if you would've used `*` instead of `?`, you would've been saying `File` can contain zero or *more* `Annotations` elements.

Valid examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE File [
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations?)>
<!ELEMENT Annotations (State*)>
<!ELEMENT State EMPTY>
]>
<File/>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE File [
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations?)>
<!ELEMENT Annotations (State*)>
<!ELEMENT State EMPTY>
]>
<File></File>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE File [
<!ELEMENT File (Annotations?)>
<!ELEMENT Annotations (State*)>
<!ELEMENT State EMPTY>
]>
<File>
  <Annotations/>
</File>
```

Comment: So containing zero elements is the same declaration as saying: this element will have an ending slash on the same line? That was my question actually...

Comment: Yes. Zero means that you can have an empty element (element with no content). That really has nothing to do with an ending slash being on the same line. XML editors and/or processors may treat line breaking differently. I've added a couple of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. The examples are exactly what I was looking for.